# Margin / Padding on custom View

Tags: android, view, layoutparams

i have created a custom view

```
CameraView extends View{
     .....
  }
```

in OnCreate methode i have define as

```
    cameraView = new CameraView(this);
                LayoutParams layoutParamsCamera 
                    = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 
                            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

                this.addContentView(cameraView, layoutParamsCamera);
```

but this use full screen i need to use as 
marginBootom= 20dp or paddingBoototm= 20dp

so how i can add this parameter to LayoutParams??

i need help
& sorry for my bad English

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`MarginLayoutParams`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams.html) instead of whatever flavor of `LayoutParams` you're now using to set view layout margins programmatically.